# Safari: want cmd-click to open tab behind, not make it active

Tags: safari, macos, tabs

In Safari, I want cmd-click to open the new tab behind my present tab, *not* also make the new tab active. I thought it was supposed to work the way I want by default. E.g.

[image]

Comment: Works this way here, do you have any extensions installed which may interfere?

Comment: ah, i posted my answer before the picture arrived… let me know what happens & I'll tweak the answer… or bin it...

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah, my bad on the initial image link. You could probably delete your answer now, it was that there extension what did it.

Comment: I'll leave it, just in case anybody finds the question on Google & it *might* help [so long as people don't downvote me into submission ;)

Answer (score 1):

Doh. When I disable the [DirectLinks](http://canisbos.com/directlinks) safari extension, it works correctly. Hat tip to @patrix.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is switchable in Prefs > Tabs

Under the options, you are given a description of each possible action...

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  click opens new tab

[image]

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  click opens new tab & also brings it to the front

[image]